# Jekyll: Error: Site could not be built, wrong date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, jekyll

When I run this in my command line:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

I get this error:

> Invalid date '': Document 'vendor/cache/gems/jekyll-3.3.0/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.

The front matter in the faulty file looks like this:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   <%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>
categories: jekyll update
---
```

I have updated my gems and installed *Xcode*. But I still get this error. I run this on: `Macbook, macOS Sierra, 10.12`.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you please post the frontmatter

Comment: And also can you try changing the date in file name to a valid one

Comment: Do you have a vendor/ folder? If so, you need to exclude it in the _config.yml file.

Answer (score 5):

If you install gems with bundle using `--path` flag you need to exclude `vendor` file, so you just need to add `vendor` in the `_config.yml` file.

```
title: Lorem ipsum
author: Lorem
...
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - vendor
```